# Likelihood ratio test for non-Gaussian distributions

Tags: distributions, likelihood-ratio

I am learning about the likelihood ratio test. Is the LRT applicable for non-Gaussian distributions too? Up to now I have only been able to find examples of the LRT for Gaussian and Gaussian mixture models.

Comment: why do you think it might not be? Gaussian is simple and nice and almost everyone - in practice - believes everything is Gaussian so "the focus shall be on it" is a fashion/markt-driven issue :-)

Comment: @Math-fun Maybe my search isn't efficient but I am not able to find any references or articles which use LRT for such distributions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at Neyman-Pearson Lemma :-)

Comment: I'm curious what you did to search, since typing *likelihood ratio test* into our search bar turns up as its second hit a question about a non-Gaussian case. Then after that the fourth, sixth and seventh hits (which is as far as I looked) are all non-Gaussian; some of them are answered, too, though their mere existence answers your question). What were you searching for?

Answer (score 2):

The [Neyman-Pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma) lemma is pretty general and is not limited to the Gaussian case. Also see the Wikipedia article on the [likelihood ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#Simple_hypotheses), which simply refers to some $f(x|\theta)$.

Searching our site on *likelihood ratio test* turns up numerous examples of questions about non-Gaussian cases.

There are also at least four examples in the "Related" section in the sidebar on the right side of this page.